# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass on #create for my #update validators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am working on the validators for my user update. However it seems like for some reason that parts of them are affecting the #create part when making a new user. Thus disallowing users to create their profile.

```
with_options on: :update do |update|

update.validates :about, :city, :why_join, :individuality, presence:true
update.validates :about, length: { in: 20..150 }
update.validates :why_join, :individuality, length: { in: 20..500 }
update.validates :country, length: { in: 4..40}
update.before_save :format_url
update.validates_format_of :city, :country, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z ]+(\d+)?\z/
update.validates_format_of :url_linkedin, :url_twitter, :url_facebook, :with => /\Ahttps?:\/\/[^\n]+\z/i

update.before_save {
  self.name = name.strip.titleize
  self.city = city.strip.titleize
  self.country = country.strip.titleize
}

def format_url
  self.url_linkedin = "http://#{self.url_linkedin}" unless self.url_linkedin[/https?/]
  self.url_facebook = "http://#{self.url_facebook}" unless self.url_facebook[/https?/]
  self.url_twitter  = "http://#{self.url_twitter}" unless self.url_twitter[/https?/]
end 
end
```

It's both the update.before_save that returns the undefined_method [] and the def format_url. I fail to see why..

This happens when I try to register a new users.

Comment: Please post the exact errors you are getting.

Comment: @jkeuhlen I did, it's in the title.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that your url_* are all non-nil in format_url()?

Comment: @jbeck I've just done what you see in the code above. Still fairly new to this :)

Comment: @sja post a stacktrace that you have when the error appears then. That error message is so generic I can't find the source.

Comment: @sja I mentioned that since that's the only place I see you using []. Try adding code like: 'raise if self.url_linkedin.nil? || self.url_facebook.nil? || self.url_twitter.nil?' as your first line in the format_url method. That may help you track down the exact place the error is coming from. The stacktrace is also a good place to look :)